# Error running rails server after installing jruby via rvm

Tags: ruby, jruby, rvm

I installed jruby using rvm and now when I use rvm to switch to using ruby-1.9.2 and try running my rails server in a different project I get the following errors:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- 1.8/http11
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
           require at /Users/thaiyoshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport--3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
```

I can post the full error but it is repetitive and complains about RubyKernel.java:1038 for activesupport, bundler, mongrel, and railties.

Here are the rubies I'm using:

```
   jruby-1.6.4 [ darwin-x86_64-java ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

Any suggestions? Are there things that I should be doing to avoid these types of conflicts?

Comment: Were you able to start your rails server before and now it's stopped working?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same gem file as I was before installing jruby. I am confused why I am now getting Java errors when I'm not using jruby.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't yet have all the correct gems available for your JRuby environment. Did you remember to run "`bundle install`" ?

Comment: If you type "`which rails`" into your terminal, what is the output? This will tell us which binary is being executed.

Comment: /Users/thaiyoshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails

Comment: I'm using 'rails server' to start my server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have other ideas based upon your answers. If you haven't already solved the issue, you may have to expand your question with more details. RVM usually works fine in this scenario... Oh!... unless a new bug has been introduced into RVM itself. Perhaps update RVM and try again - releases tend to be very frequent.